# Parse.com Push Notifications on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-universal

I am already using Parse Notification on WP 8.1 its working fine but now I want to build new version of windows 10 but parse push notification not working so please if anyone using parse push notification on window 10 help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pending pull request for Parse Windows 10 support. 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/pull/91

I'm using it currently and it's working.